# What does char **text = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char*)); does?

Tags: c, malloc

i just started with programming and i don't know what does this mean ..

I tried everything i could..

I know its dynamic memory allocation but don't know what all these (stars) means.
Could someone explain me, what every type is?
This is the code:

```
char **text = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
text[i] = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENG);
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java. Please remove the inappropriate tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code allocates (dynamic) memory for holding `n` strings. Each of these strings with max length `MAX_LENG - 1`.

I assume the complete original code to be:

```
char **text = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    text[i] = (char *) malloc(MAX_LENG);
```

or without the unnecessary casts:

```
char **text = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    text[i] = malloc(MAX_LENG);
```

So the first line, i.e.

```
char **text = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
```

will give you a pointer to a memory area holding `n` pointers-to-char

The loop, i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    text[i] = malloc(MAX_LENG);
```

then makes each of these `n` pointers point to a memory area with `MAX_LENG` chars.

It looks like:

[image]

So after this you have memory for `n` strings and can use them like:

```
strcpy(text[0], "HELLO");  // First string is "Hello"
strcpy(text[1], "WORLD");  // Second string is "World"
```

After this it looks like:

[image]

You can access the individual charaters like this

```
char c = text[1][4]; // c now holds the character 'D' from the string "WORLD"
```

Comment: Each string with length `MAX_LEN - 1`

Comment: To avoid type mis-match, use `text = malloc(n * sizeof *text);`

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation can look the following way. Let's assume that you have an array of pointers to string literals. For example

```
char * s[] = { "Hello ", "World!" };
```

The array designator used in expression with rare exception is converted to pointer to its first element. So the array designator `s` in most cases is converted to pointer of the type `char **`. That is it is a pointer to an object of the type `char *`.

For example

```
char **p = s;
```

Dereferencing the pointer you will get the first element of the array that in turn has the type `char *`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 2 };
    char * s[N] = { "Hello ", "World!" };
    
    for ( char **p = s; p != s + N; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%s", *p );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```

Now let's assume that you want to allocate the array s dynamically. The array has `N` element of the type `char *`.

So you need to write the expression

```
malloc( N * sizeof( char * ) )
```

The function call return pointer to the start of the allocated extent of memory where there will be the first element of the type `char *`. That is the function returns a pointer of the type `void *` to potentially the first element of the dynamically allocated array.

So you need to write

```
char **p = malloc( N * sizeof( char * ) );
```

or

```
char **p = ( char ** )malloc( N * sizeof( char * ) );
```

It is similar to the declaration shown above

```
char **p = s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers explained what it does but I want to focus on one small detail.

```
char **text = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
```

Using the types instead of objects in `sizeof` is considered as a not good practice. Why? If you change the type of the object you need to change all possible appearances of the old type. If you use the object in the sizeof - every sizeof will be calculated correctly without any changes in the code.

```
char **text = malloc(n * sizeof(*text));
```